# Testing Framework Selection: xUnit family theory

Tags: programming-practices, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

**Background:**
I am familiar with [xUnit family frameworks](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/Xunit.html) and have had experience with (shunit2, PhpUnit and simpletest). I am currently trying to find a testing framework for C++. I did a quick search for frameworks using [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B) list of documented frameworks; however, the framework I would like to use is very difficult to setup and is poorly documented. There is another framework that I have tried that was (IMHO) extremely easy to setup and integrate into my production workflow.

The difference between my framework of choice (the one that is difficult to setup) and the one that I'm currently using (the one that was easy to setup) is compliance with xUnit methodology.

**Questions:**
1. I have read quite a few articles about xUnit testing frameworks. I believe that they use similar naming conventions and testing methods for their test. Is this true and what are the naming methods utilized?
2. Does staying with xUnit testing frameworks make it easier to run integration tests when using multiple languages?
3. From a training perspective is it more cost effective to teach new programmers a set of tools based on the same concept or different individual tools that do the same thing?

*I kept the frameworks that I am looking at anonymous because I am more interested in industry best practices than a comparison of the two said frameworks*

Comment: As your coworkers are probably unfamiliar with all of the frameworks, I would choose the one that is the easiest to work with and comes with the best documentation. This without regard for the 'family' of frameworks that it comes from.

Comment: Sound advice. They'll probably more receptive to something that's easy to set up than to something that fits all the patterns, but is more than a hassle to work with.

Comment: @BartVanIngenSchenau I think I was able to reword the question to fit standards. If it does would it be possible to reopen it? Otherwise it's fine to leave as is. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: If five users agree that the question is now answerable, then it will be reopened. For the record, I think it should be.

Comment: @BartVanIngenSchenau Understood. Thanks for your review of the question and I'll we waiting for the approval of other users.

Comment: My initial thinking is that, when it comes down to C++, a unit testing framework will have to employ a number of techniques to workaround the issue of lack of reflection (run-time discovery of classes, types and method calls). There are many techniques, but each technique has its own shortcomings. It is the shortcomings that make people love or hate a particular C++ test framework.

Comment: I have gone through a number of different C++ testing frameworks and some of them even go as far as using other programming languages such as Python or Ruby to assist in the test discovery and run process. C and C++'s lack of reflection has played a part in this? @rwong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that while a set of tools in the same family might sound like they should all be the same (specifically I'm thinking of log4x, which is an awesome log library and much better than things like the .net logging stuff) it is still different enough in its configuration and use to practically be separate tools.

So I would not stick with a single family of tooling, and would use whatever tool you liked best, regardless of its provenance.

I find this kind of thinking prevalent in the Microsoft world - "we use Microsoft here" and no matter how bad the Microsoft tool might be, or how wonderful the non-Microsoft tool is, some people will simply not use the good stuff, and will stick with whatever Microsoft gives them. (It used to be the same with IBM, and I'm sure other places have the same mindset). The problem here is that they restrict themselves to the idea that there is stuff out there that is actually better.

So use the tooling you think is best. If you (and everyone else) refused to use a non xUnit test framework then there would be little incentive for people to come up with new, better ways of solving the problem. Using the better quality product is industry best practice IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I understand the logic and completely agree. Would it be possible to get a specific example or a case study that illustrates this more clearly?

Comment: @DodziDzakuma I'm not sure what you need. You could look at a Linux migration (eg Munich) but that is a bit extreme. Just look for non-Microsoft-funded case studies for any tech that runs on Windows, or [some comparison studies](http://theiterator.com/2009/01/log4net-vs-enterprise-library-logging-application-block/)

Comment: Got it. Will look up some non-Microsoft funded case studies and see if I can find anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done TDD in C++, but I am currently reading *Working Effectively With Legacy Code* and my first instinct would be to go with something recommended by Michael Feathers.

1. In my experience it's the *concepts* that are more important than the *names* of things. So in the xUnit style, you have the concept of a test suite which contains a group of tests, a setup procedure, and a teardown procedure. The setup is run before *every test* in the suite, and the teardown is run after *every test.* So any framework that has these concepts should be easy for someone with xUnit experience to adapt to.
2. Integration tests are a different beast than unit tests. The xUnit style frameworks don't really focus on integration. Web folks have developed specialised tools that 'auto-pilot' a Web browser to test website behaviour, but I believe a more general approach is taken by something like Fitnesse, which lets you specify expected inputs to and outputs from a system, and test those are fulfilled.

   I will say that you want to keep an eye on automated tooling--especially to see if your build tool can understand your test framework output and present it in reports, notifications, etc. It's *not enough* for a framework to just print out stuff to the console--it has to be able to give you something that your continuous integration system can use to check for build success and test pass/failure (e.g. Travis CI).
3. Not sure I understand this--it seems too general. But see # 1.